# WSO2 API Manager Installation can not run Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am brand new to WSO2 API manager and I am trying to install the API Manager for the first time on a Linux VM machine.

Java-8 has been installed. JAVA_HOME is defined and points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle. It has been verified by running: `echo $JAVA_HOME` and it looks correct.
JAVA_HOME and path are both defined in /etc/environment file.

On the WSO2 side I downloaded it and I am trying to run the wso2server.sh executable.

I keep getting this error

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly
>
> CARBON cannot execute java

Comment: Do you echo $JAVA_HOME and run the APIM in the same terminal window? If yes, please post a screenshot with all your commands.

Comment: Bhathiya how did you know , I ran everything in the in the same terminal window and it fixed the problem. Thank You :)

Comment: Yeah that happens. :) I'll put it as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run all the commands in the same terminal window.

Or you can run `source` command for the modified file before you start APIM.

Or after setting JAVA_HOME, you can start a new terminal window to run APIM.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem earlier. The reason I think java version. Bcz I have changed my java version to 1.7 and all wso2 products works properly.
Don't use open jdk. Install oracle java. Follow below link to install oracle java on ubuntu.

Change profile file as follows,

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_45
JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Comment: I did not try this as I wanted to use java 8!